# A book about space adventurer who saved planet's "primitive" culture by monopolizing its artefacts

Tags: story-identification, books, space-opera

In the 2010s, I purchased a discounted paperback (not an antique). I read it in English as a kind of pulp, read-once-and-forget piece, but certain details have stuck with me, enough to want me to re-read the book, albeit not enough to identify the story after all these years.

- I'm sure it was part of a series and obviously not the first installment.
- The main protagonist is a sort of "Space adventurer," a smuggler or something similar, and the captain of a ship.
- His crew was composed of two members: a male and a female, who were in a romantic relationship.
- The female character was some kind of superpowered alien or at least a highly capable fighter.
- The captain is gay, which is not accepted in the book's universe. He may have used the services of a male sex worker at one point and became melancholic because, unlike his friends, he can't have an open relationship, though it is not explored much further.
- The majority of the story takes place on a "primitive" planet in an isolated star system.
- The male crew member becomes isolated on a planet and goes on to help resolve its internal political struggle.
- Meanwhile, the "default galactic regime" learns about the planet and threatens to invade/forcefully uplift it. This is prevented by the captain, who claims a monopoly over the planet's artifact exports (or persuade one of his benefactors to). This legal loophole delays the invasion, giving the planet's inhabitants time to prepare for it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember the cover art?

Comment: The image I had associated with this one for years proven to be a different book entirely, so no. Unfortunately my memory is unreliable on this one. Maybe I vaguely remember red-black combination, but I won't bet my limb on that.